# query by filter related field

Tags: apex, soql

I want to filter opportunity by account but I'm getting error that a.Id is not valid token.
Could you maybe suggest what's wrong with it?

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
for (Account a:accounts) {
     List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id 
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE AccountId = a.Id];
}
```

Comment: You forgot a colon before :a.Id, but performing a soql inside the loop is a bad practice.

Comment: Also see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)

Answer (score 3):

When using a variable in a query (i.e. binding a variable), you need to use `:`

e.g. `WHERE AccountId = :myAcct.Id`

That said, queries in a loop (like what you're trying to do) are bad. We only get 100 queries per transaction.

For this particular code snippet, you should look at using a parent-child subquery to get both the Accounts and their related Opportunities in a single query. [Using relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using) will help.